# rewriting parameters .htaccess inside a folder

Tags: .htaccess

I want the url

```
domain.com/user/user.php?id=sam
```

To `domain.com/user/sam`

I already have the following .htaccess outside the `user` folder..

```
Options -MultiViews 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$" 
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

I tried many solutions, didn't work except this one(placed in user folder)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user/user.php?id=$1 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ user/user.php?id=$1
```

But what this does is redirect the url to `domain.com/user/?id=`

How can i fix it?

Update:

```
Options -MultiViews 
RewriteEngine On 

ErrorDocument 404 404.shtml
ErrorDocument 401 401.shtml
ErrorDocument 403 403.shtml
ErrorDocument 400 400.shtml
ErrorDocument 500 500.shtml

## don't touch admin/yshout/ URIs 
RewriteRule ^admin/yshout/ - [L,NC]

## don't touch controller/ URIs 
RewriteRule ^controller/ - [L,NC]

## don't touch server/ URIs 
RewriteRule ^server/ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+user/user\.php\?id=([^&\ ]+) 
RewriteRule ^ /user/%1? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ user.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$" 
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't match the query string in a rewrite rule. Try:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+user/user\.php\?id=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /user/%1? [L,R=301]
```

And make sure it's the first rule, then add this right below it:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ user.php?id=$1 [L]
```

You also don't want to make the rewrite base `/`, you can remove that line or change it to `/user/`

Comment: I have updated my question with your solution..it gives 500 status..please help..sorry i'm really bad with .htaccess